# Getting Error while deleting Cart item using DestroyAPIView with Javascript. (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using **DestroyAPIView** with Javascript to delete the cart item in Django

While clicking on delete button it shows the following error on *chrome* `console`:

```
jquery.min.js:2 DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata/2342; 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
destoryCart @ (index):46
onclick @ (index):1

(index):55 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

and in *vs code* `terminal` showing:

```
Not Found: /showdata/2342;
```

and all my code goes here:

**views.py**

```
class CartDestroyAPIView(DestroyAPIView): # DeleteView
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] # Or anything else you want
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]  # Or anything else you want
    serializer_class = productserializers
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata ',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
              var row = 
              $('<tr><td style="font-style:bold">'
                +data[i].product.name+'</td><td style="font-style:bold">'
                  +data[i].product.price+'</td><td><a href='
                    +data[i].product.link_href+'><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Buy</button></a></td><td><button onclick="destoryCart('+data[i].product.id+')" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button></td></tr>');
              $("#tableProduct").append(row);
            }
          }
        });
    });
    
    const destoryCart = (id) => {
      let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata/${id};`
      $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', "{{ csrf_token }}");
        },
          url: url,
          type: 'DELETE',
          success: (data) => {
              console.log("deleted!");
          },
          error: (err) => {
              console.log(err);
          }
      });
    };
    </script>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('cart_destroy/<int:pk>', views.CartDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name ='cart_destroy'),
```

**WHAT IS WRONG GOING WITH THIS CODE.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your URL in ajax call you have to put this URL in side your `destoryCart()`

```
 let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart_destroy/${id};`
```

instead of this `URL` `http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata/${id};`

**UPDATE**

get `csrf_token` like this i don't know if there is another way but as per official [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax).

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

And you `ajax` call

```
    const destoryCart = (id) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'cart_destroy' %}",
            data: {
                'product_id': id,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        },
        
        success: function(success) {
        console.log('success : '+success.responseText)
        },
        
        error: function(error) {
        console.log('error : '+error.responseText)
        },
        
        });
    
    }
```

and you have to update your `URL` also like this

```
path('cart_destroy/', views.CartDestroyView, name ='cart_destroy'),
```

add this in your `views.py`

```
def CartDestroyView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
      product_id = request.POST['product_id']
      Cart.objects.filter(id=product_id).delete()
      return HttpResponse({'Success':"Deleted Successfully."})
```

Comment: sir, any other solution for deleting the cart item. like yesterday we have done for showing cart to the user

Comment: Hello @santoshChauhan Let us continue this discussion in chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233789/discussion-between-santosh-chauhan-and-ankit-tiwari